# Is there any pattern to the dice in Mat's head?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

The dice in Mat's head seem to rattle quite often. I was wondering if there was any discernible pattern to them? Such as "once they start, the event is X hours away" or something like that? He doesn't seem to try to determine anything other than what will make them stop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't any consistent timeline for when they start to when they stop.

They seem to start when events are set in motion that can lead to an important moment in time where a decision must be made or chance has to go his way. They're [related to his *ta'veren* nature](https://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=836#24), which doesn't really operate on a fixed timeline.

In the series, we see some times where the dice roll for a relatively short amount of time, to essentially spanning entire books. Although the amount of time passing in each book varies greatly, it's clear that there are variation in how long the dice roll.

Comment: Yes, my understanding is they basically keep rolling for specific moments where his luck will have extremely important effects (on the whole world?).  When they stop rolling; something generally is set in motion.  I'm trying to remember if the multiple book roll was related to the events in the Towers of Midnight.  That seems like it would make sense to me; but I don't remember if it was that, or something else that was a looming dice roll.

Comment: @JMac And there were times when there was more than one set rattling around in his noggin.